# Ctrl-drag in xcode doesn't work despite same class name

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10, watchos-5

I have been adding labels to my storyboard in my 'BowlerController' scene and pairing them up with the code in BowlerController.swift file.

However, after adding 5 labels, I tried adding another label(after adding some other functionalities in other interface controllers). I noticed that the control-drag has stopped working.I can drag the line to the code but the insert action line doesn't show up so I cant pair the code with the label.

All other solutions to this issue point towards a mismatch in the interface class name and the class name in the .swift file. I haven't changed anything so that should not be the issue. I am also attaching a screenshot for reference

The new label I am trying to add is right at the bottom and is named 'label' in the storyboard.

Can anyone help me figure out why I can't ctrl-drag any more

[image]

Comment: A few things to try: Clean build folder and Derived Data and restart app.  Right click on the storyboard ViewController and confirm the correct outlets are still linked correctly without errors.  If none of that works delete and recreate the outlets.  I've seen this bug in XCode before.

Comment: added the line in the controller code, changed the label name in storyboard to newLabel but it still didnt connect

Comment: @AlexBailey : Didn't work. Do you recommend deleting all the existing outlets that are bound right now? They seem to be working fine.

Comment: yeah sounds like your storyboard is corrupt for some reason.  Flush things out to try and reset it.  It could also be that you have the wrong file open in your dual pane view (try to manually select the file).